# Flutter-Firebase Document Entry for First Time Login

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want a Flutter Code for Writing Google Sign in and Making Entry in Database in Firebase also for first time he  be able to edit His username and Profile Pic?

Comment: Have you tried any code yet? If so, could you post it?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to follow the community rules.

Comment: I have not tried any Code yet. I am just  Searching for a Code I am done Google Sign part just need my Application to Make User Entry for First time Sign in in Database